# Sql update not working in java(no errors though) but works if I place same syntax in mysql workbench

Tags: java, mysql

(NEWBIE)

```
public Response editingData(String vin, String editArea, String edit) {

   Response result = new Response();



   try{

       PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE car SET ? = ? WHERE vin = ? ");

       stmt.setString(1, editArea);
       stmt.setString(2, edit);
       stmt.setString(3, vin);

       stmt.execute();

       result.setMessage("Data updated!!!");
   }catch(Exception ex) {


       result.setMessage("Error");
   }

   return result;

   }
```

This code should try to execute a preparedStatement and set a response once thats done, else it should catch any errors and set a response, then it should return the response

```
private Response editCarDetails(){

    String vin = ui.getCarVin();
    String editArea = ui.editArea();
    String edit = ui.edit();

    Response result = carDB.editingData(vin, editArea, edit);

    ui.displayResponse(result);

}
```

This module simply sets the values of for the editingData() module, it runs the editingData() module storing its return response value in A response named result and then displays it. Yet nothing is changed in the database...

"UPDATE table SET column = newValue WHERE id = value" works fine in mysql workbench. I've also tried hard coding my value in a string instead of using a preparedStatement, but I get the same results NOTHING. I've read through different questions on stack and though I learn a few useful things none of it help my current situation.

Comment: I don't think you can bind the column in your query, and you definitely should be running `stmt.executeUpdate();` (not `stmt.execute();`)

Comment: suppose you sql query should be like this. `UPDATE car SET "+ editArea +" = ? WHERE vin = ?`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE car SET "+ editArea +" = ? WHERE vin = ? ");
stmt.setString(1, edit);
stmt.setString(2, vin);
```

You can't bind a table or column. You should bind the value.

Comment: Welcome @WillieZeroCool . So now you can accept & upvote the answer.